Electrically Changing Battery Pack's Setup
I was planning to make a small power bank that has a 6650mAh Battery capasity which has 7 950mAh Batteries. now my plan is to use it to discharge using a single battery and charge the other batteries at the same time. as I need it to charge the other 6 batteries and I need to use a Type-C Connector to charge it. my goal is to have a charging time of 1 hour and the Type-C Connector able to only output 5A Max. I thought if I use the other pending 6 batteries as 2S Packs then I can use the Type-C Power delivery board to get to 9V and then able to use less than 3.4A of current.
Now my question is can we change the tracks of the batteries so that is turns as a 2S3P Pack when charging and 1S6P while discharging. I found that we can use two track change switches and get is done. 
But I need it to be done electrically so that the BMS MCU can have better control on which battery to discharge and which to charge. now I can use relays but it's too big. and About MOSFETS it is able to work for the upper battery, but it doesn't seem right for the lower battery because the MOSFETs go in between the batteries. if there is a solution to use N-Channel MOSFETs in the both track change switches
